# Web icons copyrightable?

Tags: copyright

i have a question pertaining to the copyrights of web content. 
I understand that the web design of a website belonging to a business is protected by the copyright law. However can this be said for web icons that exist on the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are original works of authorship, they are copyrightable.

[17 USC §102](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/102):

> Copyright protection subsists [...] in original works of authorship fixed in any tangible medium of expression, now known or later developed, from which they can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device. Works of authorship include the following categories:
>
> [...]
>
> (5) pictorial, graphic, and sculptural works
>
> [...]

Comment: Another question, if these web icons are used by another website, albeit at a much smaller size, does this still count as a copyright infringement?